# why does str_replace replaces my character with a semicolon?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP (so no bullying please) and I'm trying to trim a variable to remove quotation marks. For some reason, my quotation marks are replaced by semicolons, anybody knows why ?

Where `$movieArray["title"] = '"Veronica Mars"';`

```
str_replace('&#x22', '', $movieArray["title"]);
```

output: `;Veronica Mars;`

Also, the reason I have this `&#x22` instead of this `"` is that the trim doesn't work with `"`.
Thanks

Comment: Are the quotes in your string "smart tags" like `‘` and `’` or is it a simple `'`

Comment: I believe they are this     '

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your text is *not* `"Veronica Mars"`. It's probably this:

```
&#x22;Veronica Mars&#x22;
```

If you strip `&#x22`, only the `;` remains.

What you see in the browser screen is the result of *rendering* some HTML code.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. Can't believe I didn't get that by myself. Thank you.